# Add rep vector to dataframe with uneven total rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rep

I'm trying to find a way of automating a large dataset to add two factors but the data may contain uneven rows.

I've tried to do this with the 'rep' function but this will only work if the data frame has even numbers.

```
x<-c(1,3,5,7,9)
y<-c(2,4,6,8,10)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
df$state<-factor(rep(1:2))   

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, state, value = 1:2) : 
replacement has 2 rows, data has 5
```

How do I get the data.frame to recycle 1 into row 5 instead of an error?

Comment: Or `rep(1:2, length.out = 5)`?

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur but your answer is only sufficient for individual data frames, but will not work when dealing with multiple different data frames, all with different row lengths, i.e. 1,133 rows, 1,865 rows, etc.

Comment: what about `rep(1:2, length.out = nrow(df))`?

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur, that's brilliant I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rep()`'s `length.out` argument is one option:

```
df$state<-factor(rep(1:2, length.out = nrow(df)))
```